# Capture a local pointer by value and the rest by reference in a lambda

Tags: c++11, lambda

I would like to capture a local pointer in my lambda expression. Currently my code looks like this

```
MYButton* button;
button->onPress = [index,&](control*){
            button->foobar(x, y);
    };
```

I get the error

> Error:(835, 13) variable 'button' cannot be implicitly captured
>   in a lambda with no capture-default specified

I was under the impression that using `&` in the capture clause meant capture everything in local scope by reference. In that case why am I getting this error ?

Comment: You pretty much only ever want to capture locals by reference if you want the lambda function to modify them and affect the local, or if they are expensive to copy.  Certainly for a pointer like this, you would prefer to capture by value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no capture default identified, because the capture default must be the first item in the captures. See [cpp reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) for details.

The correct code should be

```
MYButton* button;
button->onPress = [&,index](control*){
            button->foobar(x, y);
    };
```

Also, the capture `index` does not appear to be used. You can eliminate that, in which case the code would be

```
MYButton* button;
button->onPress = [&](control*){
            button->foobar(x, y);
    };
```

And, as Chris Dodd mentioned, the use of this lambda will probably be out of the scope of this code fragment, in which case you should capture by value to avoid a dangling reference:

```
MYButton* button;
button->onPress = [=](control*){
            button->foobar(x, y);
    };
```

From the [cpp reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda):

> If a non-reference entity is captured by reference, implicitly or explicitly, and the function call operator of the closure object is invoked after the entity's lifetime has ended, undefined behavior occurs. The C++ closures do not extend the lifetimes of the captured references.

One more comment. While default capture looks nice on paper (one character, no fuss), I like to be explicit with captures to reduce the risk of errors like the ones pointed out above. It also makes it easier to identify which variables the lambda relies upon. In which case the code becomes:

```
MYButton* button;
button->onPress = [button](control*){
            button->foobar(x, y);
    };
```

This is just a change in style--it means the same as the example immediately prior to it, but should be less error-prone when revising code later on.

Comment: Eliminating the `control *` argument will likely make the assignment fail as the lambda then doesn't match the type of the callback `onPress`...

Comment: I am getting this `Error:(830, 31) '&' must precede a capture when the capture default is '='`

Comment: Did you leave `index` in the capture list?

Comment: Note that "If the capture-default is =, subsequent simple captures must begin with & or be *this (since C++17) or this (since C++20)."